# Why won't react state update specific value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, reactjs, state

Preface, I'm a super noobie but here goes anyway:

I'm working with React, a user inputs a landing page, I want to scrape that landing page with JQuery and RegEx, and update the state with the value.

My issue is the state won't update values that use Jquery and RegEx to scrape the external landing page, even though those functions return the correct values (at least, I see the correct value in the console).

Below, onChange in my HTML input is where I "should" update the state. The function getProduct1Title is what should (and I think does) return the correct value, but the state's key, "Product1Title", is still undefined.

```
onChange={e =>
    this.setState({
    product1URL: e.target.value,
    product1Title: this.getProduct1Title(e.target.value)
    })
}

getProduct1Title = e => {
    $.get(e, function(response) {
        var title = response.match(
            /<h1 class="semi-bold h1">(.*)<\/h1>/
        )[1];
        console.log(title);
        return title;
    });
};
```

I expect that when I console.log the state, I see the correct values for all keys. Currently, I see all the correct URLs in the state for product1URL, but values that require me to use Jquery and Regex, like product1Title, are "undefined".

Comment: You can start by logging `this.getProduct1Title(e.target.value)` and make sure it's the expected value just before setting the state, and work from there

Comment: React events are nullable, so it's possible they are getting nullified and the event object is handed back to the pool.  What value are you getting in state for `product1Title`?  React's `setState` is also asynchronous, so if you're trying to console.log your state right after the setState call then chances are it hasn't fired yet. If you want to see state right after an update then you need to add a callback to the setState, `setState({...}, () => console.log(this.state));`.

Comment: @MatthieuLibeer, just tried it and I get undefined. But the console.log in the function, getProduct1Title, gives me what I want. Could it just be an issue of where I'm putting the return?

Comment: Correct, adding an answer with the full solution

Answer (score 0):

[`$.get`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) is asynchronous, so you cannot set the state util its [promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) is resolved.

```
onChange={e =>
    const url = e.target.value;

    $.get(url, function(response) {
        var title = response.match(
            /<h1 class="semi-bold h1">(.*)<\/h1>/
        )[1];

        this.setState({
            product1URL: e.target.value,
            product1Title: this.getProduct1Title(e.target.value)
        });
    });
}
```